# Half angle proof in Blinn-Phong reflection model

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{n,l,r,h,v \}$ be unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. It is known that all of these vectors lie on the same plane. Furthermore, it is known  that $h = \frac{l+v}{||l+v||}$ and $r = 2(l \cdot n)n - l$ where $\cdot$ represents the Euclidean dot product.

Let $\phi$ be the angle between $r$ and $v$.
Let $\psi$ be the angle between $n$ and $h$.

Prove that $2\psi = \phi$

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.